# laravel route not rendering all the components as expected

Tags: laravel

I have the following in my web.php

```
Route::resource('admin/post', 'Admin\PostController');
```

The problem is, when I hit `loclhost/admin/post/create` it does not load my view as expected.

It doesn't load a pic and a few components in my editor in the view but when I change it to :

```
Route::resource('admin', 'Admin\PostController');
```

It loads the view as expected!

An explanation of why this is happening and how to fix it will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put `Route::resource('post', 'Admin\PostController');`
inside the group it work's fine! Then you can access 
`admin/post` and `post/` and this two routes will use all methods of `Admin\PostController`.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::resource('post', 'Admin\PostController');
});
```

Now you can  access `loclhost/admin/post/create`

Comment: Thanks, that's working but when I use a resource controller my blade's picture and and the icon in my Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 are not rendered so in my body I've got no option to add a video link, change font size, insert image etc

But when I'm not using a resource controller then it's just working perfectly well!

Comment: @AlphyGacheru, may be this is happening for your src path.

Comment: Yes you are right, it was in my src path and I've fixed it. Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: @AlphyGacheru please accept this answer if it really helped

Comment: It was helpful and if by accepting you mean clicking on the "This answer is useful icon" then I already did! I'm new to stackoverflow so if that's not what you meant then let me know so I can do it as it is required. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're experiencing is likely due to conflicting route definitions or route parameter conflicts.

When you define the route as admin/post, Laravel interprets it as a route parameter where "admin" is a parameter and "post" is a value for that parameter. Therefore, when you access the URL /admin/post, Laravel treats it as a request to a route with a parameter named "admin" and a value "post". This can cause conflicts with other routes or route parameters.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).